# $.each in ajax request from php controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am starting to work with ajax and php I have a problem I am making a request ajax, pediant post of a php driver and estoi returning in format json the result from the controller .. the data that I need arrive perfect already realize the tests. In my condition if, if there is the same, I have to address otherwise an alert .. my problem is that in case it is not the same it goes well it shows me the alert, but when it is true it shows me the alert and directs me, I am Doing something wrong in the $ .each ???

```
$('#klik').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>home/validate',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

           $.each(data, function(i,item){
              if (item.Url === 'sales/index'){

                   window.location.href = 'http://localhost/sis_sales/sales';
              }
           });
           alert('You do not have permissions');

        } 
    });       
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you always show the alert. You should only do that when nothing is found. A simple and readable solution is to set a boolean variable only when an item is found, and then, after the `each` loop, check for that boolean:

```js
$('#klik').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>home/validate',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

               var found = false;

               $.each(data, function(i,item){
                  if (item.Url === 'sales/index'){
                       found = true;

                       window.location.href = 'http://localhost/sis_sales/sales';
                  }
               });

               if (!found) {
                   alert('You do not have permissions');
               }          
            } 
        });       
      });
```

To improve this code, I would send an explicit code from the PHP. For instance send a code that determines whether you have permission or not. That way, you can show a more specific error message. Now you assume that a user doesn't have permission if the url is not found, but there could also be a server error, or just a lost connection causing a failed transfer..

Even better: Don't return a status text, but also an HTTP result code. When someone doesn't have permission you could return a 403 code. You can catch these with the `error` handler of the ajax request, and check for the code to see what exactly went wrong. That makes it possible to find the different between a server error (500), a permission denied (403), or any other error.

Comment: Maybe a small error. I think if you write `var found = true` instead of just `found = true`, I think this code might already fail.

Comment: You can give me some page or a reference link, to better understand how to improve my code, and to handle user permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/sis_sales/sales';
```

Is not a blocking call/operation. It means that your code will continue to run after this line and will hit to *alert()* call. You can modify your code and define control variable as follows;

```html
$('#klik').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>home/validate',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

               var pageToRefresh = '';

               $.each(data, function(i,item){
                  if (item.Url === 'sales/index'){
                       pageToRefresh  = 'http://localhost/sis_sales/sales';
                  }
               });

               if(pageToRefresh == ''){
                   window.location.href = pageToRefresh;
               }else{
                   alert('You do not have permissions');
               }

              
            } 
        });       
      });
```